# Column aggregates filtered by row values with pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a better (faster) way to do this?

I would like to find the total sold on a given day in the same place as the person is on that day:

```
    day     name    sold    place
0   mon     Ben     2       1
1   mon     Amy     6       0
2   mon     Sue     7       1
3   mon     John    9       0
4   tues    Ben     9       1
5   tues    Amy     4       0
6   tues    Sue     10      1
7   tues    John    5       0
8   wed     Ben     8       0
9   wed     Amy     3       0
10  wed     Sue     10      1
11  wed     John    3       0
```

The result would look like this:

```
    day     name    sold    place   sold_at_same_place
0   mon     Ben     2       1       9
1   mon     Amy     6       0       15
2   mon     Sue     7       1       9
3   mon     John    9       0       15
4   tues    Ben     9       1       19
5   tues    Amy     4       0       9
6   tues    Sue     10      1       19
7   tues    John    5       0       9
8   wed     Ben     8       0       14
9   wed     Amy     3       0       14
10  wed     Sue     10      1       10
11  wed     John    3       0       14
```

In case it is not clear, the total `sold` on Monday in `place` 1 is 2+7=9. Because Ben was in place one, his `sold_in_same_place` is 9. Amy's Monday `sold_at_same_place` is 15 because she was in `place` 0.

This is what I have come up with:

1. Get the daily total for each value of place:

   ```
   def sold_by_day_filter(df, col_name, field_value):
       """
       sums sold by day
       filtering the `col_name` on `field_value`
       """
       subset = pd.DataFrame(df[df[col_name] == field_value])

       aggregated_subset = pd.DataFrame(
           {str(field_value): subset.groupby(['day'])['sold'].sum()}
       ).reset_index()

       return aggregated_subset
   ```
2. Join each one to the original dataset:

   ```
   for val in df['place'].unique():
       df = pd.merge(df, sold_by_day_filter(df,'place', val), on='day')
   ```

   Now the dataset looks like this:

   ```
       day     name    sold    place   1   0   
   0   mon     Ben     2       1       9   15  
   1   mon     Amy     6       0       9   15  
   2   mon     Sue     7       1       9   15  
   3   mon     John    9       0       9   15  
   4   tues    Ben     9       1       19  9   
   5   tues    Amy     4       0       19  9   
   6   tues    Sue     10      1       19  9   
   7   tues    John    5       0       19  9   
   8   wed     Ben     8       0       10  14  
   9   wed     Amy     3       0       10  14  
   10  wed     Sue     10      1       10  14  
   11  wed     John    3       0       10  14
   ```
3. Apply a value to a `sold_at_same_place` column base on the value in `place`:

   ```
   df['sold_at_same_place'] = \
       df.apply( lambda row: row[str(row['place'])], axis = 1)
   ```
4. Remove the temporary column values ('1' and '0'):

   ```
   fields_to_drop = [str(field) for field in df['place'].unique()]
   df.drop(fields_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
   ```

So this works, but I have a feeling that there might be some simple way to do this with Pandas. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: groupby can take multiple columns, so part of your workflow could be groupby([day, place])['sold'].sum()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a one-liner using `transform`:

```
>>> df["sold_at_same_place"] = df.groupby(["day", "place"])["sold"].transform(sum)
>>> df
     day  name  sold  place  sold_at_same_place
0    mon   Ben     2      1                   9
1    mon   Amy     6      0                  15
2    mon   Sue     7      1                   9
3    mon  John     9      0                  15
4   tues   Ben     9      1                  19
5   tues   Amy     4      0                   9
6   tues   Sue    10      1                  19
7   tues  John     5      0                   9
8    wed   Ben     8      0                  14
9    wed   Amy     3      0                  14
10   wed   Sue    10      1                  10
11   wed  John     3      0                  14
```

`transform` takes the groupby result and broadcasts the result back up to the original index.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for, thank you! I would vote you up if I could.